# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

Tags: java, awt, nosuchmethoderror

I'm trying to debug an issue with some code given to me by my professor. Ultimately I need to take the input from the text field in the `LoginPanel` and reference this later on as the `username`.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MyCardFrame extends Frame{
    LoginPanel lp;
    ChatPanel cp;

    public MyCardFrame(){
        setLayout(new CardLayout());
        setTitle("Chat");
        setSize(500,500);
        lp = new LoginPanel(this);
        cp = new ChatPanel();
        add(lp, "login");
        add(cp, "chat");

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        MyCardFrame mcf = new MyCardFrame();
    }
}

class LoginPanel extends Panel implements ActionListener{
    TextField tf;
    MyCardFrame mcf;

    public LoginPanel(MyCardFrame mcf){
        this.mcf = mcf;
        tf = new TextField(20);
        tf.addActionListener(this);
        add(tf);        
    }       
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        //using setName instead of setUserName     *********
        mcf.cp.setUserName(tf.getText()); //call setUserName of chatpanel which is a member of mycardframe
        CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(mcf.getLayout());
        cl.next(mcf);
        tf.setText("");

    }


}

class ChatPanel extends Panel{
    Label label1,label2;
    String userName;
    public ChatPanel(){
        label1 = new Label("Chat Panel: ");
        label2 = new Label("Name will go here");
        add(label1);
        add(label2);
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName){
        this.userName = userName;
        label2.setText(getUserName());
    }
    public String getUserName(){
        return userName;
    }
}
```

After this runs I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
    finalproject.ChatPanel.setUserName(Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

This is coming from the line:

```
mcf.cp.setUserName(tf.getText());
```

From what I can tell I have correctly called `setUserName`, and while the IDE provides no errors, on run it fails.

Also to clarify: Yes I know nobody uses AWT, but its required for this class and we are not permitted to use Swing.

Comment: It seems to compile fine for me.  Make sure you don't have another class named `LoginPanel` in your code base somewhere and/or try performing a clean/build.  Also AWT, really, everybody else stopped using that before the turn of the century

Comment: @MadProgrammer Im currently running a clean build, so there should be no conflicts. It compiles fine, and theres no errors in the IDE. It only spits out the error when the code is run.

Also, We are required to use awt for this class, use of swing will return a zero on the project. I know its dumb.

Comment: I would seriously contest the use of AWT to your professor. If they're too lazy to update the material to be relevant, that's probably not a good sign of things to come. Also, I tested your code. It runs fine.

Comment: which java ver / ide is that? what are the steps you perform to run the code? is all of that in the same java file?

Answer (score 1):

`NoSuchMethodError` means something very specific.  It says that when the code was *compiled* the class and method were successfully located, but when the code is being executed, even though the class was loaded, it did not contain the requested method.

This almost always means that the version of a jar file that was used during compilation is different from the one that is being provided at runtime.  The version at runtime is missing that method, or the signature is different and a matching method can not be found.

From the Javadoc for `NoSuchMethodError`:

> Thrown if an application tries to call a specified method of a class (either static or instance), and that class no longer has a definition of that method.
>
> Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed.

The solution is to double-check that you have the same jar file at both compile and runtime.